# How to rotate the camera in a first person character controller in Unity 3d

Tags: controller, camera, rotation, character, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity 3D game that contains a first person character controller. I'm trying to rotate the main camera on top of it to simulate the character turning its head left and right as he walks along a straight line.  My issue is that my code that rotates the camera seems to interfere with the rotation of the character controller object it is parented to.

Here is my code. The issue seems to be happening on the last line.

```
void Update () {
    //Send screen image to controller
    StartCoroutine(ScreenshotEncode());

    //the camera is parented to the Character Controller game object.  
    //Dude
    //  +-Capsule
    //  +-MainCamera

    //This code come directly from the Unity script manual
    DudeBase.transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * flrBaseMaxRotateSpeed, 0);
    //get the vector the base in pointing toward
    vctBaseDir = DudeBase.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    //get the speed of the base
    fltBaseSpeed = fltBaseMaxSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    //apply speed and direction to the character controller
    controller.SimpleMove(vctBaseDir * fltBaseSpeed);

    //The camera controller comes from the device in degress in the form of a string.
    //get the heading the controller is pointing toward
    fltCamControllerDir = ParseControllerData(strCamControllerData);
    //get the heading of the base
    fltBaseDir = Mathf.Atan2(vctBaseDir.x, vctBaseDir.z);
    //we want to point the camera the angle as the controller.
    //since the camera is sitting on top of and is parented to the base, it needs to offset by the bases heading
    fltCamDir = fltBaseDir + fltCamControllerDir;
    //set the camera's y axis angle
    MainCam.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, fltCamDir, 0);  // <=== issue seems to be here
    //if i comment out the last line, the character controller moves and rotates as expected.
    //if i uncomment this line, the camera moves on top of the character controller as expected. But,
    //the character controller itself no longer rotates.
}
```

How can I go about rotating the camera object without affecting the object it is parented to?

Comment: Where is `MainCam` being defined? Perhaps something is wrong with that? To access the main camera, normally you use `Camera.main`.

Comment: We have no idea how your FirstPerson object sits in the object hierarchy but it's generally a bad idea to directly modify the main camera.  Instead, add a new empty child object to your first person and call it head, reparent the camera to 'head'.  To rotate, modify 'head', not 'MainCamera'

Answer (score 0):

Jerdak's comment is the correct answer:

> Add a new empty child object to your first person and call it `head.
>   Make the camera a child of`head`.

When the player moves or rotates, the `head` object will move or rotate, bringing the camera with it. If you want to move or rotate the camera independently of the body, simply move/rotate the `head` without touching body.